# Finding out one combinations such that linear combinations makes zero vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Find a combination$~x_{1}\mathbf{\omega}_{1}+x_2\mathbf{\omega}_{2}+x_{3}\mathbf{\omega}_{3}~$that gives the zero vector with$~x_1=1:~$
> $$\mathbf{\omega}_{1}=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\2\\3
> \end{bmatrix}~~~~
> \mathbf{\omega}_{2}=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 4\\5\\6
> \end{bmatrix}~~~~
> \mathbf{\omega}_{3}=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 7\\8\\9
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> Those vectors are(independent)(dependent). The three vectors lie in a___.
> The matrix$~W~$with those three columns is not invertible.

Firtst things to first, as set of$~x_1=1,x_2,x_3~\text{exists}~\operatorname{s. t. }~x_{1}\mathbf{\omega}_{1}+x_2\mathbf{\omega}_{2}+x_{3}\mathbf{\omega}_{3}=\mathbf 0~$,set of vectors$~\mathbf{\omega}_{1},\mathbf{\omega}_{2},\mathbf{\omega}_{3}~$is dependent from the definition of linear dependence. So vectors$~\mathbf{\omega}_{1},\mathbf{\omega}_{2},\mathbf{\omega}_{3}~~$lie in a plane.

$$x_1\mathbf{\omega_{1}}+x_2\mathbf{\omega_{2}}+x_2\mathbf{\omega_{2}}=\mathbf{0}_{}\tag{1}$$

$$1\cdot\mathbf{\omega_{1}}+x_2\mathbf{\omega_{2}}+x_2\mathbf{\omega_{2}}=\mathbf{0}_{}\tag{2}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}+x_{2}\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6\end{pmatrix}+x_{3}\begin{pmatrix}7\\8\\9\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\tag{3}$$

$$x_{2}\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6\end{pmatrix}+x_{3}\begin{pmatrix}7\\8\\9\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$

$$x_{2}\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6\end{pmatrix}+x_{3}\begin{pmatrix}7\\8\\9\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-2\\-3\end{pmatrix}\tag{5}$$

$$~~\text{Stucked here}~~\tag{6}$$

> The combination$~0\mathbf{\omega}_{1}+0\mathbf{\omega}_{2}+0\mathbf{\omega}_{3}~$always gives the zero vector, but this problem looks for other zero combinations(then the vectors are **dependent**,they lie in a place):
> $~\mathbf{\omega}_{2}={\left(\mathbf{\omega}_{1}+\mathbf{\omega}_{3}\right)\over2}~$so one combinations that gives zero is$~\mathbf{\omega}_{1}-2\mathbf{\omega}_{2}+\mathbf{\omega}_{3}~$

$$~ \color{blue}{\underbrace{\mathbf{\omega}_{2}={\left(\mathbf{\omega}_{1}+\mathbf{\omega}_{3}\right)\over2},~\mathbf{\omega}_{1}-2\mathbf{\omega}_{2}+\mathbf{\omega}_{3}}_{\text{How these are obtained?}}}  ~\tag{7}$$

The official answer states that"one combinations that"so I interpret that there might over one solutions exist. Is this thought correct?

Comment: The solution suggests noticing that $\omega_2$ is the mean of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_3$, so that $\omega_2$ = $(\omega_1 + \omega_3)/2$. Multiplying both sides by 2, and getting everything to the RHS gives the solution.

Comment: Every multiple of a $(1, -2, 1)$ would be a "combination that gives zero", but not a solution since the problem requires $x_1=1$

Comment: @Joe Ahhh, I got it now.